# Showing that a compact Hausdorff space X and a specific quotient space may not be isomorphic

Tags: functional-analysis

Hi there I am struggling with this question：

> Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $Y$ a subset of $X$. Let $J_Y$ be the ideal of functions in $C(X)$ vanishing on $Y$.
>
> Show that, in general, $C(X)/J_Y$ may not be isomorphic to $C(Y)$.

**Here is what I have done so far:**

From the question, we know that
$J_Y={f∈C(X)∶f|_Y}$, $C(X)/J_Y ={f+J_Y∶f∈C(X)}$.

Define maps $T$ and $T_1$ as follows:
$T:C(X)⟶Im⁡(T)$,
$T_1:(C(X))/J_Y ⟶Im⁡(T)$.

Note that $T$ maps continuous functions on $X$ to continuous functions in $Y$, and $T_1$ maps functions from a quotient space $C(X)/ker⁡T$ into functions in $Y$.

Since $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, $C(X)$ is a Banach space complete with the uniform norm. Because continuous functions are bounded in compact spaces, they attain their max. and min. in $X$.
If $Y$ is open, then we do not generally have continuous functions bounded in $Y$.

For instance, consider $Y=(0,1)⊆X=R$. Define a map $f:Y⟶X$, $f=1/(x(x-1))$.
While $Y$ is continuous and well-defined in $Y$, it does not extend to $X$. Hence, there is no continuous function in $C(X)$ that could be restricted to $f$ by any mapping.

Therefore, both $T$ and $T_1$ would not be surjective maps; and by extension, $C(X)/J_Y ≇C(Y)$.

**I have checked the steps many times, but there is still a feeling that there is something very wrong. Could you please tell where I went wrong? Thank you**

Comment: You never actually defined what $T$ and $T_1$ are.  It's also totally unclear how you concluded that $C(X)/J_Y\not\cong C(Y)$ at the end.

Comment: The problem statement is also ambiguous: what does "isomorphic" mean?  Isomorphic just as vector spaces?  As $\mathbb{R}$-algebras? (Or $\mathbb{C}$-algebras? Are your functions real-valued or complex-valued?)

Comment: Hi Eric sorry about the ambiguity, I am going to edit the question right away. Isomorphism in this context is a bijective map T between two normed vector spaces such that both T and T^-1 are linear and continuous. The functions are assumed to be complex-valued.

Comment: $C(Y)$ is not a normed vector space in general, though.

Comment: I think I understand where I went wrong - not knowing the definition inside out. There is one thing I don't follow though, why is C(Y) not a normed vector space in general? Wasn't that given since Y is a subspace of a compact Hausdorff space?

Comment: The definitions of $T$ and $T_1$ make no  sense to me.